# db4o, how to update an object if a field was added?

Tags: c#, db4o

How can I do this?
I stored an object in db4o, 
e.g:

```
class Person {
    string _name;
    int _age;
}
```

now, after hundrets of Persons stored in the db, I've added a new field:

```
class Person {
    string _name;
    int _age;
    bool? _newField;
}
```

When I load the old classes with the new class, the _newField will be null or the default value. When I save it back to the db, the added field is obmitted.

How can I update all existing objects with the new field? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, when you add a new field it has the default value for existing object. Now you just can load a object, set a value to the field and store it again. Then the data is stored for that field. See also on the [documentation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/net35/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/refactoring_and_schema_evolution/automatic_refactoring.htm).

So you should be able to load a object and update it:

```
IObjectContainer container = ...
var persons = from Person p in container                  
              select p;

foreach(var p in persons){
     p.NewField = true; // new value
     container.Store(p);
}

// done
```

I think the default value for a Nullable bool should be 'empty'.

If that doesn't work, it looks like a bug. Which version are you using?

Comment: Ok, the field seems to be updated. But the "VisualStudio Objectmanager Plugin" doesn't show it. I'm using 7.12.132.14217

Comment: Oh, then it could be a ObjectManager bug.