# How do you change the schema in an OO database such as DB4O?

Tags: java, database, db4o, object-oriented-database

Just getting started with DB4O object oriented database.

I'm very familiar with SQL, if I upgrade the app and add a new field I just go into a SQL manager, change the schema, and initialize a new field with some manual SQL.

What is the process with an OO database such as DB4O? Is it similar?

Comment: See if this thread giving you any idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805120/db4o-how-to-update-an-object-if-a-field-was-added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: as long as you are only **adding fields**, db4o will take care of schema management for you.

For more details, check the db4o reference documentation about "[Refactoring and Schema Evolution](http://developer.db4o.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/java/reference/index_CSH.html#implementation_strategies/refactoring_and_schema_evolution.htm)". Also, you can check out the "[Schema evolution](http://books.google.com/books?id=SXG19zl8qF4C&pg=PA348&lpg=PA348&source=bl&ots=w7zPw-I4Uj&sig=pTABdiHbEhmsHa-Xg02xCToNqPU&ei=2CHFTLDlIsuPcamOmcwN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCQ)" chapter in "[The Definitive Guide to db4o](http://books.google.com/books?id=SXG19zl8qF4C&printsec=frontcover)"